# Converting the given equation in $y=mx+c$ form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to convert the below formula into $y = mx +c$. I have it on excel graphically as a solved equation, but no matter how hard I try I'm having a hard time identifying what "$c$" is equal to:

\begin{equation}
\Delta E = \frac{1}{8m((N+1)l)^2} \left[ \left(\frac{N}{2} + 1\right)^2 - \left(\frac{N}{2} \right)^2h^2 \right]. \tag{1}
\end{equation}

My $x$ term is $1/(N+1)$, so I've pulled that out separately, but now I'm trying  to separate $m$ and $c$:

\begin{equation}
\Delta E = \frac{\left(\frac{N}{2} + 1\right)^2 - \left(\frac{N}{2}\right)^2h^2}{8ml^2(N+1)} \times \frac{1}{N+1}, \tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $h$, $m$ and $l$ are constant.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Are you even sure this is a linear equation in $\frac{1}{N+1}$?

Comment: @Dominique if you look at the answers, you can see it's not in general.

Answer (score 0):

If $x = \frac 1{N+1}$, we can solve it for $N$ to get $N = \frac 1x - 1$ and substitute that into $\frac{(\frac{N}{2} + 1)^2 - (\frac{N}{2})^2h^2}{8m((N+1)l)^2}$ to get \begin{align}\frac{x^2 \left(\left(\frac{1}{2}
   \left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)+1\right)^2-\frac{1}{4} h^2
   \left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)^2\right)}{8 l^2 m}&=\frac{(x+1)^2-h^2 (x-1)^2}{32 l^2 m}\\ &=\frac{1-h^2}{32 l^2 m}x^2+
   \frac{1+h^2}{16 l^2 m}x+\frac{1-h^2}{32 l^2 m}\end{align}

Therefore, function is linear with respect to $x = \frac 1{N+1}$ if and only if $h^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the equation
\begin{equation}
\Delta E = \frac{1}{8m((N+1)l)^2} \left[ \left(\frac{N}{2} + 1\right)^2 - \left(\frac{N}{2} \right)^2h^2 \right]. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
If we now replace $N$ by $\left(\frac{1}{x}-1 \right)$, we get
$$
\Delta E = \frac{1}{8m((\left(\frac{1}{x}-1 \right)+1)l)^2} \left[ \left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}-1 \right)}{2} + 1\right)^2 - \left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}-1 \right)}{2} \right)^2h^2 \right]
$$
Simplify $\rightarrow$
$$
\Delta E = \frac{1}{8m(l/x)^2 \cdot 2^2} \left[ \left(\frac{1}{x}+1 \right)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{x}-1 \right)^2h^2 \right]
$$
$$
\Delta E = \frac{x^2}{8ml^2 \cdot 2^2} \left[-\frac{h^2}{x^2}+ \frac{2h^2}{x} - h^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{2}{x} +1 \right]
$$
$$
\Delta E = \frac{1}{32~ml^2} \left[-h^2+ 2xh^2 - x^2 h^2 + 1 + 2x +x^2 \right]
$$
Perhaps you can see the problem with the assumption that this would be linear with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does not work since you can't simply factor out $1/(N+1)$, as $N$ remains as a variable in the rest of the expression. To illustrate, $x\cdot(x+1)$ has $x$ factored out, but it would not be a linear function of $x$. A more fruitful approach would be to write your unsimplified expression in terms of $x$, by working out how $N$ relates to $x$, and then simplifying that.